# turning multiple jQuery functions into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i have a few jquery functions that i need to be turned into one.

```
// Show hidden paragraphs
$("#no678").click(function(){
    $("#imperial_number, #imperial_number2").hide();
});
$("#no678").click(function(){
    $("#metric_number, #metric_number2").show();
});
```

that's what my code looks like and I have around 7 of these I need to be turned into one.

i have no clue how to move forward with this.

Comment: Remove the second `click()` handler, and put the `.show()` line after the `.hide()` line. If you need more specific help, please add more code to the question showing all relevant HTML and JS

Comment: I was about to answer, but the I realized that I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. This is probably also why you didn't get any response. Can you explain in more detail what should happen. Include some of your HTML as well.